# How to test checkboxes with react-test-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library, jsdom

I'm using a recent version of create-react-app (in package.json, "react": "^17.0.1")

I'm trying to use react-test-library to test an app where checking checkboxes increments a counter.
I've boiled down the problem to the most hello-world form I can manage. I've tried keyDown, click...

The text expects '2' and receives '0' :

**Component file:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState  } from "react";

function App3() {
  const [counter, setCounter]= useState(0);
  const handleClickInCheckbox = (ev) => {
  setCounter(2)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleClickInCheckbox} id="chkbx" data-testid="ch1" ></input>
      <h1 data-testid="h1" >{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App3;
```

**Test file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, act,  screen, fireEvent,  getByRole} from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import App from '../App3'

describe ('app', () => {
      test('checking boxes should increment counter',
      ()=>  {
             act( 
                   ()=>{
                    render (<App /> );
               const ch1 =   screen.getByTestId('ch1')
               const h1 =   screen.getByTestId('h1')
               ch1.focus();
               fireEvent.keyDown(document.activeElement)
               fireEvent.keyDown(screen.getByTestId('ch1'))
                 expect(h1).toHaveTextContent('2');
                 }
                )
             }
 )
})
```

I tried using jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen, but that doesn't change anything
In package.json:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant event *is* `.click`, but also you shouldn't put `act` around the whole test:

```
describe ('app', () => {
  test('checking boxes should increment counter', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const ch1 = screen.getByTestId('ch1')
    const h1 = screen.getByTestId('h1')
               
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('ch1'))
    })
    
    expect(h1).toHaveTextContent('2')
  })
})
```

In this case it actually works without `act` at all, because nothing asynchronous is happening, but when you do need `act` it should be focused on the points where you expect the state to change.

Comment: moving the 'expect' outside the 'act' was indeed what allowed the test to pass